# Inverted colours after waking up from sleep mode

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, color, beta

My 2020 MacBook Air M1 shows inverted colours when it wakes up from sleep mode after several hours.

I installed macOS Monterey beta 12.1, so I am not sure if the problem is related to that or if it is a Hardware failure (which is strange too me because it really just happens after the device has been in sleep mode for multiple hours.)

[image: With open Windows]
[image: Login Screen]

Comment: You'll have to test on a release version & report it as a bug if it's OK on release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug with the current macOS beta, Apple is aware, and a fix is (probably) on its way. In the meantime, turning the brightness to max and back down temporarily fixes it for me.

---

[image: image showing Apple's knowledge of the bug in feedback assistant]

Comment: Thank you - I will wait then (and probably switch to stable releases because this is not the first Issue I've encountered with the beta releases)